# Webform adding custom component or modify radio buttons

Tags: 7, webforms

I need to make a webform that will display the radio buttons like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odmxkqy2/), where the label is above the radio button. Do I need to make a new webform component to achieve this or can I just modify the default to add the div and change orientation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with CSS alone.

Comment: By default the label is printed second [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jkrfnxLd/) is how it is defaultly rendered.

Comment: @fullerja is correct. You can use transforms or flexbox for a CSS only solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425665/switching-the-order-of-block-elements-with-css

or you can probably override the component output in a custom module if you really have to and your css-fu isn't great enough (but then your php better be good).

I would try the CSS approach 1st. It should survive webform module updates easier.

Comment: Thank you for providing an example! I will look into this!